# How i can create dynamic accordion component EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, components

I found a ready accordion [solution](https://tedconf.github.io/ember-collapsible-panel/). I tried to use it, but I don't know how to give this component a variable number of records:

My component template:

```
{{#search-results-accordion
  currentPage=currentPage
  totalPages=meta.totalPages
  items=items
  onPageChange=(action "onPageChange")
  as |item|
}}
  {{requisite-accordion-item item=item}}
{{else}}
...
{{/search-results-accordion}}
```

Parent's template(search-results-accordion):

```
{{#if (gte items.length 1)}}
  <div class="items" data-test-search-results>
{{#cp-panels accordion=true as |panels|}}
  {{#each items as |item index|}}
     {{yield item panels=panels}}
  {{/each}}
{{/cp-panels}}}
  </div>
...
{{/if}}
```

Child's template(requisite-accordion-item):

```
  {{#panels.panel as |panel|}}
    {{#panel.toggle}}
      <p>Panel A</p>
      <div class="name"><b>{{item.name}}</b></div>
    {{/panel.toggle}}
    {{#panel.body}}
      {{item.info}}
    {{/panel.body}}
  {{/panels.panel}}
```

Then I get EmberError in console: "Assertion Failed: A helper named "panels.panel" could not be found"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN5cm.jpg)

How I can use this for variable amount of records?

Comment: try `cp-panel` instead of `panels.panel`

Comment: @kumkanillam then I get the basic usage, but I need an accordion type

Answer (score 0):

Here are my observation in your code,

- In search-results-accordion.hbs, instead of `{{yield item panels=panels}}` say `{{yield item panels}}`.
- But you are receiving only `item` in components template but you should receive `item,panels` and include both arguments to `requisite-accordion-item item=item panels=panels}}`

I haven't used this addon. For debugging, you can try `{{log 'panels object' panels}}` that will print object in console.

Comment: I haven't `panels` in my model. I think `panels` it's somethink in `cp-panels`.

Comment: You can create http://ember-twiddle.com, and include addon in twiddle.json addon property so that others can get clear picture of the exact problem you are undergoing